# Limit Firebase Realtime User Records When an auth claim doesnt exist

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Ok, So i have done some googling and research for this use case and it's been hard to find an answer.

I have a firebase realtime db where i let users create records under their own user id. I want to create a rule that states if the user does not have a custom claim of "admin" they can create up to 5 records. if they have the admin privilage they create as many as they want.

is there a way to check number of children in a firebase realtime db rule?

Comment: I'm not sure about rules, but you certainly could do that with cloud functions. Or on the client side, depending on your use case.

Comment: With security rules, It's not possible to check the number of children without also keeping track of the count yourself in another location.